# Magento wont add a product into the cart, it gets stuck loading

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome, magento

When I'm on the page in google chrome or firefox, select a size and quantity of item and then select add to cart, you can see the item 'fly' into the cart in the background, but the page gets stuck on the loading screen before the item lands in the cart. It seems to work fine in other browsers, is there a way to skip the loading faze?

My site for you to test: http://reform-fitness.com/index.php/

Answer (score 0):

When i'm on a product page I get the message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PROTECTED in /home/refosnli/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_vigo/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml on line 26
```

Try to fix this and see if it helps.

Comment: That was when we were playing around with it earlier. It still isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While you're using ma_vigo theme you should have support from developer (plazathemes). Create ticket [here](http://plazathemes.com/tickets/) and provide ftp access. They'll fix it for you (as they made for their themes that did we buy) and release complex update to final version.